# How to get live data from a cell in Excel to a webpage for statistical purposes?

Tags: excel, web

I want a variable on a webpage to update live each time a cell in an Excel file gets updated. Kind of like a live counter. Any ideas? Maybe through JavaScript or something?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. First of all, what have you tried so far? What have you searched around for? I recommend seeing [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). SO is not a "code for me" site, but rather "help me with my code". If you have made some attempts, please show us the code and let us know where you're having trouble.  Otherwise, I would Google around and make some type of attempt and then come back with code where you're having more specific issues.

Comment: Thanks Bruce Wayne, I don't have any code yet, so I will now follow your steps.